# Can't receive JSON array being posted to me by third party

Tags: asp.net, json, vb.net, asp.net-web-api

The format I am receiving is:

```
[{"item1": "value1","item2": "value2"},{"item1": "value2","item2": "value4"}]
```

The main issue seems to be that no matter what I try I receive the error "`Type System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary'2 Is Not supported for deserialization of an array.`"
Scouring the internet only comes up with my needing to wrap the array in a top level variable (ie. the array cannot be on the root level). Unfortunately I am unable to change what and how I am receiving the data.

Here is all my code with the things I have attempted commented out:

My test ajax used to simulate what the third party will be sending to me:

Head of "test.html":

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    function testPost() {
        var theData;

        theData = '[{"item1": "value1","item2": "value2"},{"item1": "value2","item2": "value4"}]';
        //theData = '{"item1": "value1","item2": "value2"}'; //I can make a single array element work, but that is not what I will receive

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            url: "test2.aspx/test_array",
            data: theData,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(msg) {
                alert(msg);
            }
        });
    }

    //-->
</SCRIPT>
```

Body of "test.html"

```
<input type="submit" value="test Post" onClick="testPost();" /><br>
```

Test.aspx.vb in it's entirety:

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization

Partial Class test2
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    '    Public Shared Function test_array(ByVal item1 As String, ByVal item2 As String) As String ' works if I am passing a single array element
    '    Public Shared Function test_array(ByVal theobj As Object) As String ' "Type System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2 Is Not supported for deserialization of an array."
    '    Public Shared Function test_array(ByVal theobj As List(Of Object)) As String' "Type System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2 Is Not supported for deserialization of an array."
    '    Public Shared Function test_array(ByVal theobj As Test_Request) As String ' "Type System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2 Is Not supported for deserialization of an array."
    '    Public Shared Function test_array(ByVal theobj As List(Of Test_Request)) As String' "Type System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2 Is Not supported for deserialization of an array."
    '    Public Shared Function test_array(ByVal theobj As Dictionary(Of String, String)) As String' "Type System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2 Is Not supported for deserialization of an array."

    <System.Web.Services.WebMethod> _
    Public Shared Function test_array(ByVal d As List(Of Test_Request)) As String

        Return "test"

    End Function

End Class
```

The "Test_Request" class:

```
Public Class Test_Request
    Property item1 As String
        Get
            Return m_item1
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_item1 = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_item1 As String

    Property item2 As String
        Get
            Return m_item2
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_item2 = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_item2 As String
End Class
```

Please let me know if I failed to include any needed data. I have been going in circles for a few days now and before deciding to post here I attempted to recreate all my failed attempts in this test mock up. Hopefully there is simply something I am overlooking.

Comment: sounds like your deserialize code is trying to force the list into a dictionary

Comment: Which I am gathering is just how asp.net receives arrays posted to a WebMethod, I have yet to find away to get around it though.

Comment: you should post the deserializing code

Comment: I have posted every line of code in it's entirety (with exception of some of the HTML file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you are trying to deserialize an array of dictionary objects.  I would do something like as follows.

On the server side:

```
<HttpPost>
<Route("test")>
Public Function test(data As YourArray) As String

    Return "done"
End Function
-----------

Public Class YourArray
    Inherits List(Of YourDictionaryObject )
End Class

Public Class YourDictionaryObject 
    Inherits Dictionary(Of String, String)
End Class
```

I just tested and I can confirm that the following does work:

```
function doTest() {
    var theData = [];
    theData.push({
        item1: "value1",
        item2: "value2"
    });
    theData.push({
        item1: "value3",
        item2: "value4"
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: "somewhere/test",
        data: JSON.stringify(theData),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg) {
            alert(msg);
        }
    });


}
```

I checked and the Request Payload looks like this:

```
[{"item1":"value1","item2":"value2"},{"item1":"value3","item2":"value4"}]
```

This gets deserialized on the server side as YourArray. By the way, I am using Asp.net Web Api (not WCF where serializing/deserializing dictionaries can be tricky).

Comment: I believe I am missing an "import" statement for <HttpPost> and <Route("test")> to work, could you tell me what that is (or maybe it's the version of .net). I have this app as "web forms" using .net 2.0.

Comment: It seems you are using Asp.net webforms, whereas my solutions is relying on asp.net web api.  In any case, I am using standard web api routing attributes as described here:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx

Comment: I would recommend using a much newer version of .net.  and reference this link for using web api with webforms:  http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/whats-new-in-visual-studio-2013/one-aspnet-integrating-aspnet-web-forms,-mvc-and-web-api
Basically, download Visual Studio 2015 Community (its free) and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thank you so much for the links. If my memory serves, I'm using an older version of .net due to some limitations of other WebMethods in the project. I'm willing to bet that I can overcome those with web api and attribute routing. I'll mark your answer as accepted now and read, learn, re-write all of this later.

Comment: You are very welcome.  I struggled with serializing/deserializing json dictionaries in WCF.  Switching to asp.net web api makes this sort of thing so easy.  I recommend taking the time to moving wep api; will save you lots of headache later and is fun to work with.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Your poco is wrong.  Item1 and Item2 need to be string arrays

```
Public Class RootObject
       Public Property item1() As String
       Public Property item2() As String
End Class
```